# Extension notification when there is change in browser window size

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

I've developed a Firefox extension that needs to be notified whenever there is a change in the browser window size.

I used `gBrowser.addeventListener("resize",my_funcion,false);`
in my .js file of extension.
But this will be notified very frequently when you change the browser window size by dragging. I require the final value of window parameter *after* resize is done, *not during* resize.

Which event should I register to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `gBrowser.addeventListener("resize",` attach a resize listener to the window or the tabbrowser? I always thought `gBrowser` was a shortcut to the tabbrowser element.

When I've had to listen to window resize events, a queue system seemed like the best option e.g.

```
var queue=0;
var chromeWinOuterHeight;
var timer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/timer;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITimer);

function chromeWinResize(e){
    queue++;
    timer.initWithCallback(function(){
        if(queue>1){
            queue--;
        }
        else if(chromeWinOuterHeight !== e.target.outerHeight){
            //do stuff
        }
        chromeWinOuterHeight = e.target.outerHeight;
    }, 500, Components.interfaces.nsITimer.TYPE_ONE_SHOT);
};
chromeWindow.addEventListener('resize',chromeWinResize,false);
```

Comment: i've just copy paste the above code into my extension's .js file but it wasnt working for me. is there in prerequisite need to use this code. i'm failed to register to the event i think. help me

Comment: chromeWindow was just my reference to the chrome window.